# [object atIndex:row]; is not working- objective C

Tags: ios, uipickerview

How can I get the value of selected row of a `uipickerview`?
I have row value using the code;

```
    int row;
    row = [PickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];// row value is ok
    [object atIndex:row]; //is not working?
```

Waiting for your help?

> UPDATION:

actually i want to get the value of pickerview which is selected by-default when it is loaded...

Comment: What do you mean by this `[object atIndex:row];`

Comment: yeah.. bt it is not working der..

Comment: Are you trying to select something from array using `row`? then do like this `[YourArray objectAtIndex:row]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use its delegate method.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
[object atIndex:row];
}
```

Comment: actually i want to get the value of pickerview which is selected by-default when it is loaded...

Comment: when its first time loaded then none value is selected, you have to manually use setselected method to select row at first time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
NSInteger selectedRow =[self.singlePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
NSString *title = [self.data objectAtIndex: selectedRow];
```